# Cannot determine Location in iPod?

Tags: ios, maps, location, ipod

I have new iPod, Open maps application in my new iPod, then select location service option in left corner and loading fraction of second, then to show "Cannot determine Location".
Then i tried to reset network settings ans reset all settings also but its no helps. 
Choose new Wi-Fi network also, same thing happened.
How to fix this? Please help me

Thanks in Advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3986705?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer in [apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3986705?start=0&tstart=0). Your iPod may not be having GPS capability. This is what mentioned there,

*GPS signals are separate from and completely unrelated to both the Internet and the cellular telephone network.  GPS signals come directly from the GPS satellites.  They provide latitude and longitude information to GPS receivers.  Navigation software then takes that latitude/longitude info and converts it to land mass, roads, bridges, highways, buildings, etc.*

*Most navigation software stores the maps right in the iPad/iPod/iPhone but a disadvantage is that the maps must be periodically updated (perhaps once every two years).  The Internet is not required to use the system but it is required to update the maps.*

*Some navigation software gets the maps from the Internet and requires an Internet connection to function but an advantage is that the maps are always up-to-date.*

*The WiFi+3G/4G iPad and the iPhone both have a GPS receiver.  The WiFi-only iPad and the iPod do not and these devices require an accessory.*